# Iam policy to request tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is the policy I was trying to allow creation of instances only when it has tags costcenter and dept with values 115 and prod .but when I test it the instance getting created even with out these tags

```html
 {
            "Sid": "AllowTaggedInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:729964090428:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "115",
                    "aws:RequestTag/dept": "prod"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "costcenter",
                        "dept"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The policy that you showed, does not have enough permissions to create an instance. This means that you have another policy or role that is overriding this one.

In your policy replace the word "RequestTag" with "ResourceTag".

Note: The best policies using conditions do not use "allow if this" but instead use "deny if NOT this". A deny will override all allows.

Here is a link to help you with ResourceTags:

[EC2 Resource Tags](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

Your policy is not enough permission and policies to restrict.

If you want to allow user to create new instance with tags `costcenter:115 and dept:prod`, try below policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:Describe*",
        "ec2:GetConsole*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:region::image/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:key-pair/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/costcenter": "115",
          "aws:RequestTag/dept": "prod"
        },
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "costcenter",
            "dept"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:*/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```